# Valid way to move bits in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm working on an assignment for school and I'm getting strange output.  So, I figured I should start checking some of my more basic methods before I get to the fancier ones.  The question I have is this: 
would the method

```
public static short get16(byte a, byte b){  
    return (short)(a*Math.pow(2,8)+b)
}
```

return a `short` where the first 8 bits are byte `a` and the last 8 bits are byte `b`?
I don't see why it wouldn't, since multiplying by `2^8` would be the same as left shifting 8 bits to the left. And adding the second byte would make up for the 8 0's achieved by multiplying by `2^8`. Is this correct?

Comment: Don't do integer calculation by calling floating-point functions and then rounding the result. "Math.pow" is a floating-point function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you should know:

"Math.pow" is a floating-point function. Don't do integer calculation by calling floating-point functions and then rounding the result.

Java virtual machine is internally a 32-bit system. All "byte" and "short" mathematical expressions are internally evaluated as "int". Even an addition of two bytes goes internallly like this: 1) convert the bytes to ints, 2) add the ints, 3) convert the lower 8 bits to byte.

The correct way is:

```
return (short) ((a << 8) + (b & 255));
```

or

```
return (short) ((a << 8) | (b & 255));
```

When "byte" is converted to "int", the sign bit gets copied into the new bits. For example 0b01010101 becomes 0b00000000_00000000_00000000_01010101, because the first bit was 0, but 0b10101010 becomes 0b11111111_11111111_11111111_10101010.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend using `Math.pow` to compute 256.  `pow` is notoriously hard to implement correctly; some extant implementations don't even get the exact cases right!

Also, `byte`s in Java are signed, so you probably want to say `(a&255)` and `(b&255)` rather than just `a` and `b`.  Sign extension will ruin everything for you.

Comment: That's the thing, I need to do everything using the sign bits.  I'm supposed to create and implement my own cpu using registers in java.  My assignment is to take the 8-bit one that we made, and turn it into a 16-bit but still keep legacy support for the 8-bit op codes.  I turned my accumulator into two byte variables, but every portion of my code that uses addition is off.